# ¿Como evitar la duplicación de un elemento html, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Buen día.
Actualmente utilizo `.append()` para agregar como elemento una respuesta del servidor al html.

De la siguiente forma:

```
$('.DescripcionProductoGratis').append(response.data.DescripcionProductoGratis);
```

El problema que tengo es que por cada vez que se ejecuta la función que contiene la respuesta del servidor, va duplicando el elemento  `DescripcionProductoGratis`, como puedo evitar esa duplicación.

Visualmente se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como verán contiene el texto "Tienes derecho a un Producto con valor de: 460 - 9588 Lima de Pies", dicho texto lo tiene 3 veces, ya que por cada vez que le doy al checkbox ejecuto la función donde realizo el `.append()`.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Necesitas que ese dato se quede y agregue otros o que cuando se vuelva a ejecutar la funcion el nuevo dato pise al que ya esta y muestre siempre uno?

Comment: exacto, siempre debe ser 1.

Comment: Trata de usar la propiedad de jquery html(), no estoy seguro si funciona $('.DescripcionProductoGratis').html(response.data.DescripcionProductoGratis); trata de usar esto a ver si lo reemplaza.

Comment: Utiliza .html() para que reemplace el contenido completo.

Comment: Saca append y pone html, esa funcion pisa el dato en vez de sumar el nuevo: $('.DescripcionProductoGratis').html(response.data.DescripcionProductoGratis);

Comment: me ha funcionado con el .html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que utilizar el **html()** en vez de **append()**:

```
$('.DescripcionProductoGratis').append(tmp);
```

camrbiarlo por:

```
$('.DescripcionProductoGratis').html(tmp);
```

Debido aque el append va agregando elementos y el html reemplaza el contenido por uno nuevo.